# Encrypt encryted message vs DS

Tags: public-key, symmetric

In digital signature  The encrypted message is signed by the sender private key and verify using sender public key. The encrypted message is encrypted with another public private key pair which the receiver will have a way to compute those out

Instead of ds, cant the sender just encrypt that encrypted message with his own public key using symmetry key encryption? Wouldnt that be sufficient to prove that the message is indeed from the sender?

Any thoughts on this? Or ds is required

Comment: No, they shouldn't. The public key is Public anybody can use this information. DS is required if you want to know the sender. Check [NaCl's](https://libsodium.gitbook.io/doc/) `crypto_box` and `sealed_box`

Comment: I wanted that encrypted message to be decrypted to reveal another encrypted message using that public key which is made available. In DS you verify using public key of sender which is publicly available.. . Isnt this the same as i encrypt that encrypted message using symmetry encryption with public key? The inner encrypted message is itself is encrypted by another public private key pair

Comment: "i encrypt that encrypted message using symmetry encryption with public key" but everyone knows the public key, so everyone could do exactly that.